# Simple GET keeps returning 404 while in browser works perfectly

Tags: python, http

I'm trying to crawl this website: https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/

It works perfectly when accessd via browser but when I try to use the requests library in python it keeps returnin 404 for every url or sub-url from this domain. I don't understand what is happening and don't for which terms to search to solve this.

I currently use the anaconda 3 python. There is below a script for some context.

```
import requests
import sys
print('Requests version')
print(requests.__version__)
print('Python version')
print(sys.version)
print()
print('Requesting...')
result = requests.get('https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/')
print(result)
```

The output of this block is

```
Requests version
2.18.4
Python version
3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 29 2018, 16:14:56) 
[GCC 7.2.0]

Requesting...
<Response [404]>
```

I've tried other sources and adresses from their website and nothing worked. I also tried other https methods and nothing workd. I am able to get some usual sites like wikipedia and google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The website doesn't like HTTP(S) requests coming from Python code. By default, `requests` sets the following request headers:

```
{
  'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.19.1',
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 
  'Accept': '*/*', 
  'Connection': 'keep-alive'
}
```

If you set another, less obvious `User-Agent`, it should work fine. For example:

```
headers = {
   'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
}
result = requests.get('https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk', headers=headers)
```

Comment: Its an https request though, will the usual http workaround still work?

Comment: headers and user-agents work the same, whether you are in HTTP or HTTPs :)

Comment: Note that if they're intentionally blocking Python requests, they likely will block anything else you try if they're able to fingerprint the traffic. This sort of thing is a arms race.

Comment: Yeah no that i understand, ive always just wondered if the workaround basics (so header recreation, etc..) still worked

Comment: Yeah! Did this in a cybersec seminar, we ended up using a python script to deploy a django server to send the request so it seemed even less pythonic

Answer (score 2):

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: requests.get('https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/', headers={'User-Agent': 
'test-app/1.0'})
Out[2]: <Response [200]>
```

Add a user agent to your request.